# add some file from device like photo pdf ppx to my local database in application

Tags: android, database

i'm new in android and i want to do this things in my app

1) when click the button , open camera and when take a photo , this photo save on my application database and show this photo in application

2) when click other button , open file manager and select some file like PDF,ppx,music,photo,... and copy seleced file to my application database

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDS16.jpg)

and i dont know how save photo or file in my database directori folder when i add something in application from device or take photo whit camera

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: i want add some file from device to my application and show them